# Problem of failure to report a positive score

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

I wanted to understand if it's my problem only that when I get a positive score on the achievement icon (cup) you do not see the small green symbol that indicates the reputation. It's been happening to me since this morning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is considered "status by design" where the achievements icon only shows aggregated reputation if it's positive. If you had an answer upvote (+10) and downvote (-2), the aggregation would show +8. If a user was removed and it influenced your reputation (-95 in your case) and you only had two answer upvotes (+20), the aggregated total of -75 won't show.

Note that the aggregation is made from the last time you clicked on the achievements icon. So, while it might not have shown anything for your reputation loss of -75 on 2019-05-25, once you clicked on the achievement icon, the aggregation timeline resets.

Reference: [Why do reputation drops not highlight the Achievements icon?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219652/168244)